# Probability of that products with a low succes rate are defective

Tags: probability

Probably a very simple question:

Suppose a hospital orders defibrillators from a manufacturer. It is well known that defibrillations are often not effective, even when the defibrillators themselves are working properly. Suppose research shows that only 15% percent of defibrillations are effective. Over the next few months the hospital performs about 3000 defibrillations. What is the probability that none of these are successful?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple question. Hint: Binomial distribution. You have all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that "effective" and "successful" are the same (this is not necessarily the case in real life).  I'll also assume that the $3000$ defibrillations are a random sample from the same distribution as
that in the research.  Again, this is not necessarily true: presumably, the success of a 
defibrillation can depend on lots of things, especially the condition of the patient.  Also, these should be independent, so you shouldn't count two defibrillations on the same patient as separate.

If $p$ is the probability of a defibrillation being successful, the probability that none of the $3000$ defibrillations are successful is $(1-p)^{3000}$.